# How can i replace a whole row string value with another value in r

Tags: r, dplyr

The table i have is as shown below for example;

```
    V1
  hello
   name
    age
    hey
  apron
 street
  night
   soap
```

suppose i want to replace row names with starting with `"a"` by 1,`"h"` by 2,`"s"` by 3 and `"n"` by 4
how will i do it.

I want the output to look like

```
   V1
    2
    4
    1
    2
    1
    3
    4
    3
```

Comment: Aniket, the code I posted produces your output exactly.

Comment: Yes thank you, can u also help me with one more thing. Suppose i want more than one letters like startsWith(df$V1, "a","h") == TRUE~ '1', or in a range like startsWith(df$V1, letters[1:8]) == TRUE~ '1', how will i be doing it @ThomasPepperz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer below. It draws from a base function `startsWith()` and uses `dplyr` to manipulate the data using `case_when`and `mutate`. Good luck to you and welcome to StackOverflow.

```
library(dplyr)

df = 
  as.data.table(
    c(
      "hello",
      "name",
      "age",
      "hey",
      "apron",
      "street",
      "night",
      "soap"
      )
  )

colnames(df) = 
  "V1"

df %>%
  mutate(V1 = case_when(startsWith(df$V1, "a") == TRUE~ '1',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "h") == TRUE~ '2',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "s") == TRUE~ '3',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "n") == TRUE~ '4'))
```

Output:

```
  V1
1  2
2  4
3  1
4  2
5  1
6  3
7  4
8  3
```

If you want more than one letter to be replaced by the same number, simply add the new letter and specify the number you want it to change to without fear of throwing an error. In the below code, I simply changed the number value associated with 'h' from '3' to '1':

```
df %>%
  mutate(V1 = case_when(startsWith(df$V1, "a") == TRUE~ '1',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "h") == TRUE~ '1',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "s") == TRUE~ '3',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "n") == TRUE~ '4'))

Output:

  V1
1  1
2  4
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  3
7  4
8  3
```

To play around with sequences of letters, use the built-in dataset known as `letters`.

You can then use something like

```
 letters[1:4]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: can u also help me with one more thing. Suppose i want more than one letters like startsWith(df$V1, "a","h") == TRUE~ '1', or in a range like startsWith(df$V1, letters[1:8]) == TRUE~ '1', how will i be doing it. @ThomasPepperz

Comment: I added a bit of code to address your question. I'm not sure off of the top of my head how to use a range, but you can have more than one letter have the same outcome value.

Comment: thanks alot, thomas can i pass a vector of starting letters in the code in startswith, can u help me giving a range instead instead of "a" like ("a" to "g")  @ThomasPepperz

Comment: Review the latest addition to my answer.

Comment: if i put letters[1:8] then it throws NA's, i want it to replace all the values between "a" and "h" by 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
# Define the word vector
words=c("hello","name","age","hey","apron","street","night","soap")

# Define a translation list: first letter -> number
translation=list("a"=1,"h"=2,"s"=3,"n"=4)

# Select the corresponding elements in translation list
# Unlist to have a vector
unlist(translation[substr(words,0,1)])

#Output:
> h n a h a s n s 
> 2 4 1 2 1 3 4 3
```

Comment: the whole row name is not being replaced, as age starts with "a" then it should be replaced by 1, like that

Comment: This is what you get with the code proposed,  "h n a h a s n s" are just the row names, the vector is "2 4 1 2 1 3 4 3" is you asked for

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substring` to get first character and then use `case_when` to assign values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(first_char = substring(V1, 1, 1), 
          new_V1 = case_when(first_char == "a" ~ 1, 
                             first_char == "h" ~ 2, 
                             first_char == "s" ~ 3, 
                             first_char == "n" ~ 4, 
                             TRUE ~ NA_real_))


#      V1 first_char new_V1
#1  hello          h      2
#2   name          n      4
#3    age          a      1
#4    hey          h      2
#5  apron          a      1
#6 street          s      3
#7  night          n      4
#8   soap          s      3
```